# How do I clean up and unload a WebGL canvas context from GPU after use?

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

How do you clean up a WebGL context program and unload the program, buffers and everything from the GPU and dom-element?

I'd like to make sure we're not littering.

Also it'd be nice to reuse the canvas if possible (and I don't know if it'd be `2d` or `webgl` context).

Comment: stack.gl has a nice package called gl-reset. It cleans up the webgl context for re-use.

Comment: @asdf the link to the package is https://github.com/stackgl/gl-reset

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can just lose every reference to your gl context and all gl objects and the canvas and remove the canvas from the DOM. Unfortunately, because JavaScript is garbage collected there's no knowing when the browser will actually free the memory. There are some conformance tests to try to test they do this correctly but if you don't want to just hope and pray then ....

To free all your resources by calling `gl.deleteXXX` on everything you created and unbind all bind points. That means for every texture unit call `gl.bindTexture` on all targets with `null`, the same with arrays, framebuffers and renderbuffers.

```
var numTextureUnits = gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS);
for (var unit = 0; unit < numTextureUnits; ++unit) {
  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + unit);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, null);
}
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, null);
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);

// Delete all your resources
// Note!!!: You'd have to change this code to delete the resources YOU created.
gl.deleteTexture(someTexture);
gl.deleteTexture(someOtherTexture);
gl.deleteBuffer(someBuffer);
gl.deleteBuffer(someOtherBuffer);
gl.deleteRenderbuffer(someRenderbuffer);
gl.deleteFramebuffer(someFramebuffer);
```

Because you can't bind `null` to an attribute you could set the size of all your buffers to 1 (zero is not allowed) before you delete them. Either that or make a new  buffer and assign it to all attributes.

Example of the first

```
// set a buffer to 1 byte before deleting
// NOTE: You'd need to do this for ALL BUFFERS you created.
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, someArrayBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 1, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.deleteBuffer(someArrayBuffer);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, someElementArrayBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 1, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.deleteBuffer(someElementArrayBuffer);
```

Or make a new buffer and assign it to all attributes

```
var buf = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buf);
var numAttributes = gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS);
for (var attrib = 0; attrib < numAttributes; ++attrib) {
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(attrib, 1, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
}
```

This will unbind the old buffers from the attributes.

Finally set the canvas size to 1x1 pixel.

```
gl.canvas.width = 1;
gl.canvas.height = 1;
```

It's not a perfect solution but it will immediately free all but a few k of memory immediately, no waiting for garbage collection which is out of your control.

As for reusing the canvas from scratch you can't. The canvas will always have the same context you first asked it for.

Also see [@Johan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38027471/1480391) about `loseContext`

Comment: Cool, thanks for the thorough answer. Maybe for posterity you could add an example how `gl.deleteXX` looks?

Comment: Good explanation, I used it but I still see the program not getting freed up when we load a new image onto the webgl context and new set of programs are getting attached. You can take  a look at it on firefox shader editor

Answer (score 16):

To lose the context, use the extension `WEBGL_lose_context` as

```js
gl.getExtension('WEBGL_lose_context').loseContext();
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WEBGL_lose_context/loseContext

Comment: You linked to `restoreContext()` instead of [`loseContext()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WEBGL_lose_context/loseContext). Also, the first two lines suggest this does not do what you want: *"The WEBGL_lose_context.loseContext() method is part of the WebGL API and allows you to* ***simulate*** *losing the context of a WebGLRenderingContext context. It triggers the steps described in the WebGL specification for handling context lost.* ***The context will remain lost until WEBGL_lose_context.restoreContext() is called."***

Comment: @Job spec isn't the code, it can be interpreted ambiguously. However, there is also the following: _Implementations should destroy the underlying graphics context and all graphics resources when this method is called. **This is the recommended mechanism for applications to programmatically halt their use of the WebGL API.**_ Regarding the word _simulate_ - I guess it was chosen because _This extension exposes new functions which simulate losing and restoring the WebGL context, **even on platforms where the context can never be lost**_ - i.e. simulation takes place when destroying is impossible

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: IE does not support this method.