# How to reuse the WebGL context within a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl

I am trying to clear the contents of WebGL canvas.

Is it fine if I just delete the canvas element from DOM and create a new one, and most importantly, will it clear up all the resources and not cause any memory leak.

My scenario is that, I am getting images continuously via AJAX polling from the server every 20 seconds and using a hidden WebGL canvas to draw it and further using another canvas to show it perfectly.

Suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using a canvas over, let's say, an `img` tag?

Comment: its necessary for me ,  requirement of the project , I have to do all the processing on the hidden canvas and then copy that canvas to the main canvas using Fabric.js

Answer (score 1):

Basically no, if you just delete the canvas from the DOM there is no guarantee it will get freed in time to create a new one, after 8 or 16 of them you'll possibly get an error.

see [How do I clean up and unload a WebGL canvas context from GPU after use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23598471/how-do-i-clean-up-and-unload-a-webgl-canvas-context-from-gpu-after-use)

Why can't you just keep reusing the same canvas or canvases?

Comment: I want to reuse the canvas ,but the images will be of different length . and I need to update the hidden canvas width and height in order to send it to fabricjs. I have also applied the code that is coming along with the above link that you have provided but I didn't get it working somehow